# Is there an app that shows the melody of a singer on YouTube songs?

Tags: theory, chord-theory, melody

Is there an app that shows the melody of a singer on YouTube songs?

I've got a few songs that I want to analyse in terms of the melody and chords. I can easily work out the chords, but as for the melody of a song, it takes me an unnecessary amount of time. By the melody I mean the exact notes that the singer sings.

Is there a mobile app that can do it automatically like chordify.net is for chords? However, chordify.net is a bit bad because it doesn't work out the rhythm.

Comment: Melodyne is good, but not exact because singers tend to sing non-standard, or blue notes. If you continue to try to just play the melody line on an instrument, you'll find it easier and easier.

Comment: @Jonathon M - Using your blue notes idea, a piano won't work well, as often the blue notes are 'in the cracks'.

Comment: I suppose you could look at the sheet music for the songs. This comes down to almost the same as using an app, which right now won't be any more accurate than the dots. Or continue to transcribe for yourself, and improve, like most of us for the last few hundred years. Eventually it'll get betterand you'll have gained another skill.

Comment: I can read the sheet music but it's not easy to find it for any song that I like.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to get the exact notes of the singer without doing some work yourself. There is an app called melodyne from Celemony that will allow you to import audio files and it will give you a breakdown of all the notes and arrange it on a timeline in chromatic layers. The main work you will have to do is play back samples individually until you find what sounds like the main note. I've played with the app before and it works quite well.

Here's a link to their page on the app. It's not free but they have a 30 day trial. http://www.celemony.com/en/melodyne/what-is-melodyne